# Ruby on Rails 403 Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I am trying to get a simple demo of Ruby on Rails working on my local version of Apache (Mac OS X 10.6). I have a folder in the localhost linked to the public folder (/Users/david/Sites/demo/public to localhost/demo), I have permissions set to read write execute for the group and the group set to _www. I have the directory set to:

```
<Directory "/Users/david/Sites/demo/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I try to go to the site (http://localhost/demo) I get a 403 Permission denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/david/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/david/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15
PassengerRuby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

To my httpd.conf file.

Comment: Glad it worked! Yes, from the sounds of it, I was thinking it wasn't looking via passenger... glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I may be misunderstanding your question, but the problem is that you need to have something to handle the server-side code, not just a pointer to the directory - this isn't a static set of html pages, you know? You need to set up some sort of Rails webserver to run on top of Apache: mongrel is one of these, probably the easiest in my opinion if you're an apache man is Passenger.

Unless I just totally missed your question....

Comment: I believe that I have Passenger installed. That was the goal at least. I don't know if it was successfully configured or not though.